# Как сделать обтекание картинки текстом и добавить этой картинке подпись?

Tags: javascript, html, css

По вот этому гайду вставил картинку в свой проект: https://webformyself.com/kak-sdelat-v-html-podpis-pod-kartinkoj/  
Но мне нужно обтекание, текстом картинки с подписью, иначе выходит ужасно, есть какие то способы по этому методу дать обтекание текстом или наоборот, как подписать картинку, что бы сохранить обтекание? 
Так-же делал обтекание через float, но я не нашёл способ подписать картинку

```js
function showHide(element_id) {
      if (document.getElementById(element_id)) { 
          var obj = document.getElementById(element_id); 
          if (obj.style.display != "block") { 
              obj.style.display = "block"; 
          }
          else obj.style.display = "none";
      }
      else alert("Элемент с id: " + element_id + " не найден!"); 
}
```

```css
.leftimg {
    float:left; 
    margin: 7px 7px 7px 0; 
   }
.rez p{
 text-align: center;
}
.rez{
 height: 100px
 width: 100px
 float:right;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head><title>Работа Тимофеева Дениса</title>
<script src = "script.js">
</script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cscs.css"/></head>
<body>
<div onmouseover="document.getElementById('yux3').src='249.gif';"
onmouseout="document.getElementById('yux3').src='crest.jpg';">

<h1>Остров Валаам <a href="https://valaam.ru"><img id=yux3 src="crest.jpg">valaam.ru</a> </h1> </div>
<p><img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_8eb56_842bba74_XL-640x400.jpg"   width="272" height="174" class="leftimg">Валаам - остров в северной части Ладожского озера, самый большой в составе Валаамского архипелага. На острове расположен посёлок Валаам, входящий в Сортавальское городское поселение, и Валаамский ставропигиальный мужской монастырь, являющийся памятником русского зодчества. Название острова, возможно, происходит от финно-угорского слова &laquo;валамо&raquo; - высокая (горная) земля.<br> Остров неоднократно посещали императоры Александр I и Александр II, другие члены императорской фамилии. Также приезжал на Валаам святитель Игнатий (Брянчанинов). Природа Валаама вдохновляла <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showHide('block_id')"> известнейших гениев творчества и науки.</a><br/><br/>
        <div id="block_id" style="display: none;">
Здесь побывали художники И.И. Шишкин, Ф.А. Васильев, А.И. Куинджи, писатели и поэты Н.С. Лесков, Ф.И. Тютчев, А.Н. Апухтин, И.С. Шмелёв, Б.К. Зайцев, композиторы П.И. Чайковский, А.К. Глазунов, учёные М.Н. Миклухо-Маклай, Д.И. Менделеев и множество других. В XIX веке во время своего путешествия по России остров посетил Александр Дюма-отец. <div class = "rez"><img src = "https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_8eb56_842bba74_XL-640x400.jpg"><p>К.Гоголев. «На пристани»(резьба по дереву).</p></div> Хорошо известны валаамские пейзажи, написанные И.И. Шишкиным (&laquo;Вид Валаама&raquo;, 1860), А.И. Куинджи (&laquo;На острове Валаам&raquo;, 1873) и Николаем Рерихом (&laquo;Святой остров&raquo;, 1917). Ряд современных художников, в частности, известный петрозаводский график А.И. Авдышев, в 1970-х годах создал серию черно-белых линогравюр. Приезжал на Валаам и посвящал ему свои работы мастер объёмной резьбы по дереву, сортавальский художник Кронид Гоголев. Назовите ближайший город, из которого можно приехать на о. Валаам:
        </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: можете приложить ваш код?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1896JuJJIb5ggXFOJzA6lNrtsYkaLrGQo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Картинка в скрытом блоке должна быть обтекаемой, верхняя картинка тоже должна быть с подписью и обтекаемой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените изображение на свои

```js
function showHide(element_id) {
    if (document.getElementById(element_id)) { 
        var obj = document.getElementById(element_id); 
        if (obj.style.display != "block") { 
            obj.style.display = "block"; 
        }
        else obj.style.display = "none";
    }
    else alert("Элемент с id: " + element_id + " не найден!"); 
}
```

```css
.leftimg {
    float:left;
   }
.rez p, .leftimg p{
 text-align: center;
}
.rez {
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head><title>Работа Тимофеева Дениса</title>
<script src = "script.js">
</script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cscs.css"/></head>
<body>
<div onmouseover="document.getElementById('yux3').src='249.gif';"
onmouseout="document.getElementById('yux3').src='crest.jpg';">

<h1>Остров Валаам <a href="https://valaam.ru"><img id=yux3 src="crest.jpg">valaam.ru</a> </h1> </div>
<div class="leftimg"><img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_8eb56_842bba74_XL-640x400.jpg"><p>Вид Валаам</p></div>Валаам - остров в северной части Ладожского озера, самый большой в составе Валаамского архипелага. На острове расположен посёлок Валаам, входящий в Сортавальское городское поселение, и Валаамский ставропигиальный мужской монастырь, являющийся памятником русского зодчества. Название острова, возможно, происходит от финно-угорского слова &laquo;валамо&raquo; - высокая (горная) земля.<br> Остров неоднократно посещали императоры Александр I и Александр II, другие члены императорской фамилии. Также приезжал на Валаам святитель Игнатий (Брянчанинов). Природа Валаама вдохновляла <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showHide('block_id')"> известнейших гениев творчества и науки.</a><br/><br/>
<div id="block_id" style="display: none;">
Здесь побывали художники И.И. Шишкин, Ф.А. Васильев, А.И. Куинджи, писатели и поэты Н.С. Лесков, Ф.И. Тютчев, А.Н. Апухтин, И.С. Шмелёв, Б.К. Зайцев, композиторы П.И. Чайковский, А.К. Глазунов, учёные М.Н. Миклухо-Маклай, Д.И. Менделеев и множество других. В XIX веке во время своего путешествия по России остров посетил Александр Дюма-отец.
<div class = "rez"><img src = "https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_8eb56_842bba74_XL-640x400.jpg"><p><b>К.Гоголев. «На пристани»(резьба по дереву).</b></p></div> Хорошо известны валаамские пейзажи, написанные И.И. Шишкиным (&laquo;Вид Валаама&raquo;, 1860), А.И. Куинджи (&laquo;На острове Валаам&raquo;, 1873) и Николаем Рерихом (&laquo;Святой остров&raquo;, 1917). Ряд современных художников, в частности, известный петрозаводский график А.И. Авдышев, в 1970-х годах создал серию черно-белых линогравюр. Приезжал на Валаам и посвящал ему свои работы мастер объёмной резьбы по дереву, сортавальский художник Кронид Гоголев. Назовите ближайший город, из которого можно приехать на о. Валаам:
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```